# ERROR: syntax error at or near "from" in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I am doing some `RFM` model and got stuck here:

```
select "customer_id" as a, rfm_recency*100 + rfm_frequency*10 as rfm_combined
from
(select a, 
       ntile(4) over (order by recency) as rfm_recency,
       ntile(4) over (order by frequency) as rfm_frequency) x
from
(select a,
       max("purchase_date") as recency,
       count(*) as frequency
from "customer") y
```

> syntax error at or near "from"

Comment: you should count your paranthesis, ..... as rfm_frequency) x .... the next from is somehow wrong

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer:

```
select "customer_id" as a, rfm_recency*100 + rfm_frequency*10 as rfm_combined
from
(select a, 
       ntile(4) over (order by recency) as rfm_recency,
       ntile(4) over (order by frequency) as rfm_frequency
from
(select a,
       max("purchase_date") as recency,
       count(*) as frequency
from "customer") x)y
```